# Excel 2016: Sorting the precedents of a formula with relative cell references

Tags: excel, sorting

Let's say I have a range in Excel that looks like this:
[Simple Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b10Gv.png)

```
X   1
D   2
F   3
R   4
E   5
S   6
T   7
V   8
Q   9
```

And I want to take the sum of three specific values in that range. Let's say the values that correspond with E, X, and F.

I might write a formula like this:

```
=B5+B1+B3
```

That's great and gives me a value of 9 (5+3+1).

Then I decide I want to clean up my range a bit, and put col A in alpha order. When I sort the range, my relative cell references don't move in Excel 16.

The formula I wrote will remain =B5+B1+B3, which now reference the values related to D,F, and R (since the whole range has been sorted)

This seems to run absolutely counter to the whole core concept of relative cell references. I would expect that sorting, like insert/delete rows, drag/drop, or copy/paste moves and reorders the cells in the range, and so the formula that references those cells should also be altered.

In other-words, I would expect my formula to become

```
=B2+B9+B3
```

My question is why?

(It's worth noting at this point the solution to this problem is to use VLOOKUP like:

```
=VLOOKUP("U",$A$1:$B$8,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP("T",$A$1:$B$8,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP("Z",$A$1:$B$8,2,FALSE)
```

I don't need help with a technical fix so much a philosophical adjustment)

I understand that a verbose equation like the VLOOKUPs above is a much more reliable way to follow wanted values in a range that endures sorting. However, I feel I understand the philosophy of relative cell references well, and I would expect them to move with the sort!

What's more, if I were to do something like change the formatting on B5, B1, and B3, and then sort the range, that formatting would "stick" to the cell. So why does sorting uphold the metaphor of "shifting cells" as it applies to formatting, but use the metaphor of "overwriting cell" when it applies to relative references in a formula.

What am I missing?

Comment: Formulas are different than formatting.  when using relative references it is relative to the cell in which the formula is placed and not the references themselves.  So as the formula is moved around it keeps the same referential spacing from the cell in which the formula is finally placed.  BTW: `=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{"U","T","Z"))`

Comment: I suspect it is to maintain compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3.